# EXCEL vlookup to copy only 2nd instance from sheet 2 to sheet 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of client codes and emails on *Sheet1* (AC EMAIL), with the client code listed in column A and the email in column B.

[image: AC EMAIL SHEET]

I used vlookup to copy the client email to a *Sheet2* (AC ADDRESS) containing the client code and their postal address.

I used:
`=VLOOKUP(A3,'AC EMAIL'!$A$1:$B$25989,2,FALSE)`

[image: AC ADDRESS with EMAIL 1]

However some clients appear on *Sheet1* 2 or 3 times as they have multiple emails listed.

I want to extract just the 2nd and 3rd email onto *Sheet2* in another email column.

The formula I used only copied the *first email* listed, I am having trouble getting the correct formula to show when a *second email* is given.

This is what I am looking to do, on the single client code row a column showing the *first email* and a *second* or *third* column showing if another email is given.

This has proven to be less straightforward than I had hoped. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

## This is a great use for a dynamic `INDEX` `MATCH` setup using `INDIRECT` to re-target searched ranges.

### Start with the trivial case:

[image: Simple INDEX MATCH]

`=INDEX(A2:B10,MATCH(D2,A2:A10,0),2)`

Given a list of codes and names, go to the (first) row matching code and bring back the name from that row.

### But how do you get the second matching record?

Iterate over the list, searching only the rest of it after the first appearance. With `MATCH` we know where the first matching record appears - so we'll use `INDIRECT` to repeat the same `INDEX` `MATCH` function, but restricting the range to the portion of the list after the first match is found.

In other words, use the same formula but replace `A2:B10` with `INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$10,0)+2&":B10")`
(then wrap the whole thing with `IFERROR` for appearance)

Now we have:

[image: Two-layer INDEX MATCH]

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($D2,$A$2:$A$99,0)+2&":B99"),MATCH($D2,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($D2,$A$2:$A$99,0)+2&":A99"),0),2),"not found")`

You'll note that this method does rely on the Client Code column being sorted - we have hard coded a `+2` into the cell reference that defines the range - remember the original range began with `A2`, not `A1`, so we add one row to catch up, then we add another row to start the range from the next row down.

### Which should make it pretty clear what we're going to do next:

[image: Next iteration]

Just change that `+2` to a `+3` to start the search range from the NEXT row down (skipping the first *two* matching instances), to get the third instance for the next column over.

### But what if we have a lot of columns, or just don't like updating formulas?

Finally, we'll replace those `+2` and `+3` offsets with cell references too, using `COLUMN`. This makes the formula extensible horizontally without any manual edits when copying over:

[image: One Formula to Rule Them All]

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($D2,$A$2:$A$99,0)+COLUMN()-4&":B99"),MATCH($D2,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($D2,$A$2:$A$99,0)+COLUMN()-4&":A99"),0),2),"not found")`

Note that because I have my example destination data starting in cell `E2`, my `COLUMN` offset does need to be set manually, once, to `COLUMN()-4` - but once it is, ***that* formula can be written in the top left cell of your destination range and copied down and across** for as many instances as you need (again, as long as the source data is sorted by code, since the whole premise of the iterative `INDEX` `MATCH` is to repeat the search from the 'next row down').

Comment: I know it's an old question but this is *absolutely* something Excel can do in a worksheet function (without helper fields!) and this one had suffered too long without a legit answer!

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP()` does not support retrieving the second or third (or any other than the first) match. It is supposed to find *the first match that fulfills the search criteria*.

Your question does not say exactly that you always want the second, or always the third - or always the *last* match.
Assuming you *always* want the *last* match, one way would be to sort the array accordingly. Whatever data makes the entry you want be in the *last* position could be used to sort it into the *first* position (by sub-sorting that column in the other direction). If the current sequence is just historic from entering, you could add a column 'Active' and put an 'X' there (and then sort descending), etc.; or add a column with valid-date, or something like that.
Alternatively, you could identify and discard all duplicates, only keeping the 'last' = 'wanted' entries; depending on if you want to keep the others anyway.

Either way, there is no simple straightforward solution - Excel formulas are not a programming language. You can always go into VB and code it there, if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i'll try your other ideas. Cheers.

Comment: 'Either way, there is no simple straightforward solution' for certain values of 'simple straightforward', I suppose not, but it certainly doesn't take VBA, just a creative approach to using your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Given that "VLOOKUP() does not support retrieving the second or third (or any other than the first) match. It is supposed to find the first match that fulfills the search criteria." -

you have to make the lookup unique.  If you make a column for sequence that increments for doubles and starts over for new - e.g.  if(c2=c3,+b2+1,1) and then make a key column that includes the sequence - +c3&b3, then you can do your lookup on whichever sequence you want.

[image: Ed takes 2 math's]