# Splitting data into columns

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office-2016

I have a spreadsheet that I'm working on. Winthin this sheet there are two columns. Column A is the unique identifier and column B has ID numbers.  One identifier could have up to 1 or 5 ID's.  What I need done is to move all IDs into one row keeping the identifier I have attached a before and after image .

I'm sure there is some formula out there that can do this, hope you can help.

#### Before

[image: Before]

#### After

[image: After]

Comment: Easy with *VBA* macros..............................is this approach okay ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent  - I've never worked with VBA macros but I'm sure I could figure it out.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent OKay, I have opened the VBA in my excel doc, what would the code be for this type of request

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1134851/excel-vlookup-to-copy-only-2nd-instance-from-sheet-2-to-sheet-1

Answer (score 0):

Place this macro in a standard module and run it:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, Na As Long
    Dim v As String, Nc As Long

    Columns("A:A").Copy Columns("C:C")
    ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes


    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To Nc
        k = 4
        v = Cells(i, "C").Value
        For j = 2 To Na
            If v = Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Cells(i, k) = Cells(j, 2).Value
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here is some sample output:

[image]

As you see, we assume the inputs are in columns **A** and **B**.  The outputs go in the columns next to them.  The code does not care if the data is sorted or not.

Comment: Amazing!  Works great with a small number.  I've tried to use this code on a spreadsheet that holds 5000+ entries and it keeps freezing (Not responding)

Answer (score 0):

I do this every so often, but without VBA and in a couple steps:

1) first sort the data by ID so that they're grouped together

2) then, in C2: =if(A1=A2,if(A2=A3,B1&","&B2, "Last,"&B1&","&B2),B2)

3) run that down

4) copy and paste the C column as values (let's just say in the D column) to get rid of the formula

5) sort by D column, delete everything that doesn't say "last"

6) select D column, Data tab > Text to Columns > delimited > select commas > OK

Now everything is broken into unique columns and are on the same line as the ID. You can delete the B and C columns since they're no longer needed